# How to show the disk name and capacity of external storage in android

Tags: android-external-storage

I am creating an android application that had to work with the external storage.I want to display the list of external storage devices with its external storage name and its free space and its total space can any one tell me how to display capacity and free space and name of a disk in android.

I did some thing to check external devices in a list view:

```
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) {   
    Devices_Temp++;
    i += "\n" +
    "DeviceName: " + device.getDeviceName() +"\n"+
    "VendorID: " + device.getVendorId() +"\n" +
    "ProductID: " + device.getProductId() + "\n";
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    StatFs statfs = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
    long bytes_available = (long)statfs .getBlockSizeLong()*(long)statfs.getAvailableBlocksLong();
    long total_bytes_count=bytes_available/(1024*1024);
     String_Array_Dynamic_Genaration.add("Free space : "+total_bytes_count);
}
```